# stripe: iterate over ALL coupons

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe in my website. I'm trying to check if a user supplied input matches a coupon but I can't figure out how to iterate over all coupons (it appears I always need to enter a limit which can range from 1 to 100): https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#list_coupons

Here's what I've tried so far, which only returns 10 coupons which is the default:

```
coupons = stripe.Coupon.list(limit=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation, it looks like you need to paginate through the results.

Basically, you request for a first page of `N` coupons, and if there is more to fetch, you request for the next `N` coupons, starting from the last one of your previous request.

Looking at the docs, I came up with this approach:

```
def get_all_coupons(page_size=100):
    last_coupon = None
    while True:
        response = stripe.Coupon.list(limit=page_size, starting_after=last_coupon)
        coupons = response['data']
        if coupons:
            for coupon in coupons:
                yield coupon
            last_coupon = coupons[-1]
        if not response['has_more']:
            break
```

`get_all_coupons()` return a generator, that yields all the coupons, fetching 100 at a time.

---

**Note**: I have not tested this.

Comment: That works, but you don't need to do this. There is an `auto_paging_iterator` in stripe-python that handles it all for you(scroll down a little on [this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#pagination) page : `for coupon in stripe.Coupon.list().auto_paging_iter():`

Answer (score 0):

I've never used stripe but the docs say you can use the starting_after attribute to define your place in the coupons list. I don't know how to read the coupon IDs from the list it returns but you will need that.

```
# Coupons 0 - 100
coupons_list_1 = stripe.Coupon.list(limit=100)
# Get last coupon in coupons_list_1 and get its ID
last_coupon_id = '$1OFF'
# Coupons 100 - 200
coupons_list_2  = stripe.Coupon.list(starting_after=last_coupon_id, limit=100)

# Check if user inputted coupon is in either list
userinput in coupons_list_1 + coupons_list_2
```

Answer (score 0):

stripe now supports auto-pagination: https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto

```
customers = stripe.Customer.list(limit=3)
for customer in customers.auto_paging_iter():
# Do something with customer
```